# Add table row using after() and load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, row

My question is very similar to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery). I'm trying to use jquery, so that when you click on a table row, it loads certain information from another page and insert as a new row below the one clicked on.

If I didn't have to load the data from another page, I could just use something like:

```
clicked.after('<tr><td>Something</td><td>Something</td></tr>');
```

If I wanted to load and insert into something other than a table, I could use something like:

```
clicked.after($('<div>').load("Page2.aspx"));
```

So how do I go about combining these two together? If I have on the first page:

```
clicked.after($('<div>').load("Page2.aspx"));
```

And have Page2.aspx returning:

```
<tr><td>Something</td><td>Something</td></tr>
```

I would get this:

```
<tr><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr><div><tr><td>Something</td><td>Something</td></tr></div>
```

Which is not valid HTML.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `after` in the callback of a `get` rather than `load`.

```
$('.clicked').click( function() {
    var $clicked = $(this);
    $.get('Page2.aspx', function(html) {
        $clicked.after(html);
    });
});
```

Comment: You can accept this answer as the solution to your question using the check mark next to the up/down voting answers.